# Purpose of a "header"-comment

Tags: go

I recently got introduced to Go in the project I'm doing for a client. They already have an established codebase that needs some changes.

I noticed that all the methods, structs, and so on have sth of a weird header-like comment that looks like this:

```
// SomeType ...
type SomeType struct {
    // impl
}

// SomeFunc ...
func SomeFunc() *Val {
    // impl
}
```

What's the purpose of it? Is it supposed to be something akin to JavaDocs? What do the three dots at the end of every such comment mean? My IDE (GoLand) recognizes the names and turns them into links to the implementation right below. The fact that it does get parsed and treated like this makes me think it's important.

Comment: see go doc  https://blog.golang.org/godoc

Comment: @muthukumarselvaraj, That's it. Thanks!

Comment: Also covered in [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#commentary)

Comment: Note that just writing `Function ...` with a literal three dots is "cheating": you're giving a syntactic representation that makes the tools happy (so they won't complain about undocumented functions) without actually providing any documentation (so the tools that provide documentation will be useless). That's not a good idea, in the end.

Comment: @torek Oh, so that's why those dots are there. Good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it supposed to be something akin to JavaDocs?

Good guess!

This is "Godoc", specially-formatted comments that are treated as documentation by the godoc tool. You can read about how this works on the Go Blog: [Godoc: documenting Go code](https://blog.golang.org/godoc).